# Log4j output on console instead of configured file

Tags: java, file, configuration, console, log4j

I configured Log4j to log into a file but it is instead logging to stdout.
it creates the log file but it does not write to it, instead to stdout.

Here is my config file:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, file, mail
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/path-to/jobs-batch.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[jobs-batch] %p [%t] %c{1}.%M(%L) | %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc=WARN

# Configuration for receiving e-mails when ERROR messages occur.
log4j.appender.mail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.mail.To=xxx@xxx.com
log4j.appender.mail.From=xxx@xxx.com
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=mail.xxx.de
log4j.appender.mail.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=Jobs Batch Error
log4j.appender.mail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d  %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that this is the configuration file that log4j read?

Comment: Do you have permission to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was stupid by myself.
i was using the `-Dlog4j.configuration` to set my file. 
BUT i was also configuring log4j programmatically to use the SAME configuration file.

i still do not understand why it did behave like that since i was just setting the SAME configuration file twice. But once i did it only once it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust to suite your needs:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, C     
log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMddyyyy HH:mm} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.C.Target=System.out
```

Comment: i think you missunderstood the question. i do not want console output.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- What is the name of your Log4j property file?  The default is log4j.properties, which is what the Log4j library will look for on startup.
- Related to what Thorbjorn asks in his comment, where is the log4j property file located? Placing it in the default package will ensure it's found (by default Log4j searches the classpath).
- Optionally specify the location of the log4j property file using the `log4j.configuration` property when starting the JVM.

Comment: i do it with a prop when launching. and i am certain my file is used